# Why TrigramSimilarity is not working on postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I want change SearchRank with TrigramSimilarity but i got this error

ProgrammingError at /search/
function similarity(character varying, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: ...ows_show"."description", '')), 'B')) AS "search", SIMILARITY...
^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

My code:

```
def search_content(query: str) -> QuerySet | None:

if query:
    search_vector = SearchVector("name", weight="A") + SearchVector("description", weight="B")

    shows = (
        Show.objects.annotate(
            search=search_vector, similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name', query),
        )
        .filter(similarity__gt=0.4)
        .values("id", "name", "baner", "release_date", "search", "similarity")
    )
    
    movies = (
        Movie.objects.annotate(
            search=search_vector, similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name', query),
        )
        .filter(similarity__gt=0.4)
        .values("id", "name", "baner", "release_date", "search", "similarity")
    )
    
    episodes = (
        Episode.objects.annotate(
            search=search_vector, similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name', query),
        )
        .filter(similarity__gt=0.4)
        .values("id", "name", "baner", "release_date", "search", "similarity")
    )

    qs = shows.union(movies, episodes).order_by("-similarity")

    return qs

else:
    return None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you don't have the extension that contains that function in your database. Issue a

`select * from pg_extension;`

and if doesn't appear one named pg_trgm create it with

`create extension pg_trgm;`

As appear in [official documentation for using django with trigram similarity](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigram-similarity)